# Keras Value Error when checking input: expected dense_27_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 150, 150, 3)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, classification

I recently started Machine learning and I started building a binary classification model. However, I ran into an error while running my code:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
base_dir = ("/content/drive/apagdata")
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir,"train")
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir,"test")
# This returns a tensor
inputs = Input(shape=(784,))

# a layer instance is callable on a tensor, and returns a tensor
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

# This creates a model that includes
# the Input layer and three Dense layers
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "/content/drive/apagdata/train",
    target_size=(150,150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "/content/drive/apagdata/test",
    target_size=(150,150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2000,
    epochs=50,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=800)
model.save_weights('first_try.h5')
```

I received the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_3 to have 2 dimensions, but got an array with shape (32, 150, 150, 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the input of your model are images of shape `(150, 150, 3)` (since you have specified `target_size=(150,150)` in the image generator). Therefore, the input shape of the model must be the same:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))
```

And probably since you have are only using `Dense` layers in your model, you need to add a `Flatten` layer right after the input layer to flatten the images:

```
x = Flatten()(inputs)
```

Don't forget to pass `x` to the next `Dense` layer.

Further, note that you mentioned you are building a binary classifier and you have correctly set `class_mode='binary'` in the image generator; however, the last layer in your model must be a sigmoid classifier, not a softmax classifier:

```
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
```